# Fourier transform of $\exp( ic_1x^3 -c_2x^2 )$ [when $c_2=0$ it is the Airy function]

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

I'm wondering if anybody has a clue on the following integral
$$ \int_0^\infty \exp[i c_1 x^3 - c_2 x^2 + i x p] \mathrm{d}x$$
basically the Fourier transform of $\exp[i c_1 x^3 - c_2 x^2 ]$. I am interested in the case $c_1 > 0, \: c_2 >0$.

I know that when $c_2 = 0$ this reduced to the standard Airy function of $p$ (modulo some constants of course).

I've tried looking at integral tables but without luck...

Thank you for any possible advice :)

Comment: no closed form here...is one of the parameters particulary big or small?

Comment: Yeah I guessed that there is no closed form... In principle I would like to compute it for arbitrary values of $c_1$ and $c_2$, but I think I could do even for $c_1 \ll 1$
Thank you for commenting anyway :)

Comment: Apparently these integrals also got a name as special functions (Gauss-Airy functions):
http://inf.ucv.ro/~ami/index.php/ami/article/viewFile/684/546
Maybe now my question should be if there are efficient ways to evaluate this function rather than looking for a closed form...